# Create directory tree to textfile with exclusions

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

As the script should run on different windows computers from an external drive, I've got this executable batchfile so far:
create_list.bat

```
:: http://www.howtogeek.com/204088/how-to-use-a-batch-file-to-make-powershell-scripts-easier-to-run/
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%~dpn0.ps1'"
echo+
echo Done! list.txt was created.
echo+
PAUSE
```

which executes this one line in powershell:
create_list.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem | tree /F /A > list.txt
```

This works pretty well.
Now i'd like to exclude all folders "VIDEO_TS" and "subs". How can I do that?
I'm not fixed to powershell/cmd, but it should run just by double-click on most of the newer windows systems (so a .exe would also fit).

I didn't use pure batch as it messes up all the special characters like umlauts (äöü). The tree command itself doesn't support more parameters and I have absolutely no knowledge about powershell.
I tried the -Exclude parameter for powershell, but either it doesn't work or I messed up.

Is it possible to exclude directories or files this way (batch + powershell) or do I need another approach?

### /edit1: show-tree

using the [show-tree cmdlet](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Tree/1.0.0/Content/Show-Tree.ps1) from the PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)

```
. "R:\Filme\show-tree.ps1"
show-tree "R:\Filme" -MaxDepth 5 >> "R:\Filme\testlist.txt"
```

ends in a loop with this error in between (I translated):

```
Error calling method, because
[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]]
doesn't have a method named "SubString".
In R:\Filme\show-tree.ps1:136 Char:9
+         $RootRelativePath = $ProviderPath.SubString($d.PSDrive.Root.Length)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

### /edit2: Powershell version info

`$psversiontable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

## Solution

Call the script from [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274425/6131991) from another batchfile:

```
chcp 1252
CALL aschipfl.bat >> list.txt
```

Comment: can you clarify a bit, do you need to exclude ALL directories, or only the two folders you mentioned?  (either way is pretty easy in PS but different approaches)

Comment: Do you want to exclude folders by their name or by their full paths?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise enough. I wanted to exclude **all** folders (and subfolders / their content) named "VIDEO_TS". Meanwhile I found a nice script [show-tree.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Show-Tree/1.0.0/Content/Show-Tree.ps1) which seems to be able to do stuff I want, but I don't know how to make it run. If I call it by `".\show-tree R:"` nothing happens, not even an error.

Comment: There are example commands provided in that file on lines 38, 41, 44, 45, 155, 156, 157, 158 & 159. Those recursing from drive letter level, _(more than one example)_, do not look like the code you're trying!

Comment: Yes, I've seen the examples, but an error told me that the resource is not included, but available. I should use ".\show-tree". I modified the script to dot include the show-tree.ps1 and it works, but I just get a command window which runs more or less endless and I'm getting more and more |||| characters in there. No output file is created on R:\   here my commands: `. R:\Filme\show-tree.ps1
show-tree R:\Filme -MaxDepth 5 >> testlist.txt`

Comment: Just realized that I could stop the execution with `ctrl + c` to see the error between the tree-chaos (because of linewrap). See my edit in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution using recursion:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Comma-separated list of quoted exclusions for directories:
set _DEXCL="VIDEO_TS","subs"
rem // Comma-separated list of quoted exclusions for files:
set _FEXCL=
set "_FILES=" & rem // (set to non-empty value to include files as well)

rem // Global ariable indicating current directory level used for indent:
set /A "$LEVEL=0"

set "ITEM=%~1" & rem // (first command line argument specifies root directory)
rem // No root directory has been specified, so use current directory:
if not defined ITEM set "ITEM=."
rem // Check given root directory for existence and quit script if not found:
if not exist "%ITEM%\" exit /B 1 & rem (trailing "\" to not find files)
rem // Check given root directory against wild-cards and quit if some occur:
set "FLAG=#" & for %%J in ("%ITEM%") do if "%%~J"=="%ITEM%" set "FLAG="
if defined FLAG exit /B 1

rem // Process root directory in sub-routine:
call :PROCESS "%ITEM%"

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS  val_dir_path
rem // Display name of provided directory:
set "PTH=%~nx1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :INDENT PAD %$LEVEL%
echo(!PAD!!PTH!
endlocal
rem // Increase indent:
set /A "$LEVEL+=1"
rem // Process all sub-directories:
for /D %%D in ("%~1\*") do (
    rem // Check iterated directory against exclusion list:
    set "FLAG="
    for %%E in (%_DEXCL%) do (
        if /I "%%~nxD"=="%%~E" set "FLAG=#"
    )
    rem // Process iterated directory in sub-routine recursively:
    if not defined FLAG (
        call :PROCESS "%%~D"
    )
)
rem // Process all files in case they are to be included:
if defined _FILES (
    for %%F in ("%~1\*.*") do (
        rem // Check iterated file against exclusion list:
        set "FLAG="
        for %%E in (%_FEXCL%) do (
            if /I "%%~nxF"=="%%~E" set "FLAG=#"
        )
        rem // Display name of iterated file:
        if not defined FLAG (
            set "FILE=%%~nxF"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            call :INDENT PAD %$LEVEL%
            echo(!PAD!!FILE!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
rem // Decrease indent:
set /A "$LEVEL-=1"
exit /B


:INDENT  rtn_string  val_number
rem // Build indent string consisting of spaces:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "IND="
for /L %%I in (1,1,%~2) do set "IND=!IND!  "
endlocal & set "%~1=%IND%"
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I didn't even know, that it is possible with pure batch. Although now I've got the problem with the special chars - especially umlauts (äöü) back :-/  Already tried stuff like `chcp` command. Maybe I'll need another batch to run over it and replace chars.

Comment: You mean the exclusions contain such special characters? well, I could imagine it would help to place the exclusion strings in a text file (say `Dexcl.txt`, containing `VIDEO_TS` and `subs` in individual lines), so they are read the same (wrong) way as the directory tree: `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, `set "_DEXCL=" & for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%~dp0Dexcl.txt") do set _DEXCL="!_DEXCL!","%%~L"`, `endlocal & set _DEXCL=%_DEXCL%`

Comment: No, the exclusions fortunately don't contain special characters, but the output textfile does contain wrong or no chars where äöü should be. `tree /a >> list.txt` gives wrong encoded umlauts in cmd, but it works in powershell. This is the reason I used powershell.

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you tried with `chcp 437`? also `chcp 850` or `chcp 1250`?

Comment: I only tried `chcp 850` 1252 and 65001 before - with no change. Now I also tested 437 and 1250 plus the other ones again. This time `chcp 1252` worked! It must be related to my new setup:
Make a file aschipfl_start.bat with `chcp 1252      CALL aschipfl.bat >> liste.txt` and the aschipfl.bat containing your script untouched.

Comment: Its really nice to have a batch script on this.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to use the Exclude parameter in the **Get-ChildItem**

Use the below code in that case :

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Source_Test -Exclude "subs","video_ts" | tree /F /A > list.txt
```

This will do your work as requested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is one of the things I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I still get the full unfiltered output of `tree /F /A`.

Comment: Could you please share the directory list? I want to know how the folders look like. Is there any additional space and all. BEcause this works perfectly in my local.

Comment: It's something like that: http://pastebin.com/6pwu9JeX
Created with this create_list.ps1: `Get-ChildItem R:\Filme -Exclude "subs","video_ts" | tree /F /A > list.txt` It's case-insensitive, already tried.

Comment: ok in that case you have to first filter out from get-childitem using recurse. Try this then `Get-ChildItem E:\Source_Test  -Recurse -Exclude "subs","video_ts" | tree /F /A > list.txt`

Comment: I added the `-Recurse`, but it made absolutely no change. Still the same output as if I purely ran `tree /F /A > list.txt` in a batch.

Comment: Let me try from my side and see.

Comment: Ok for me it looks like it is not possible to pipe output from `Get-ChildItem` to `tree`. An own powershell-command for `tree` is needed. This command in fact does exist: `show-tree` (see answer above), but this also doesn't work and ends in a loop with errors in between.

Comment: which version you are in ? try $psversiontable and let me know

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post (couldn't write it here for formatting reasons).